# ReactDOM.render doesn't work in getUserConfirmation

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-dom

I try to test functionality of getUserConfirmation. Code is following:

```
getUserConfirmation={(message, callback) => {
          const container = document.createElement('div');
          // callback(false);
          document.body.append(container);
          ReactDOM.render(
            <div
              style={{
                width: '400px',
                height: '400px',
                backgroundColor: 'black',
                zIndex: 1000,
              }}
            />,
            container,
            console.log('Here'),
          );
        }}
      >
```

Code reacts to my attempt to change url and callback (console.log('here')) works. But nothing appears in browser. What I do wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

It works in this example:

```js
const getUserConfirmation = (message, callback) => {
  const container = document.createElement("div");
  // callback(false);
  document.body.append(container);
  ReactDOM.render(
    <div
      style={{
        width: "400px",
        height: "400px",
        backgroundColor: "black",
        zIndex: 1000
      }}
    />,
    container,
    console.log("Here")
  );
};

getUserConfirmation();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
</body>

</html>
```

However, what's the purpose of this?
Why not have a single and fixed "root div" in the html and pass this element to ReactDOM.render?

Comment: Hmm, I don't see anything in your html body... What do you mean "it works". I use it because for my case it is only one valid method.

Comment: I tested on Firefox and Chromium. Adding 'position: absolute;' makes the z-index property work, but I can see without position too. Maybe your browser has some odd CSS default.

Answer (score 0):

I added position: 'absolute' and now I can see my div. Before I it 'hided' under scripts tags. Lol